# Send FormData and more json data from ajax to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

is there any way that I can send a FormData object and a `json list` on the same ajax post request?
I have this code:

```
var formData = new FormData($('#formSlip').get(0));
```

I know this serialize the form and create a `FormData` object, I can send this `formData` using ajax and I can retrieve the file in my controller, but I need to pass a list of objects that I created dynamically in `javascript`

So I have `formData` and `tests` list, is it possible to do something like this?
(I know this code doesn't work, but the important is you to get the idea)

```
 $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        data: { file: formData, list: tests},
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        success: //some code
    })
```

I know that this code below works:

```
data: formData
```

But it just serialize the form and I'm not able to pass the `tests` list then..
Is it possible?

Comment: FormData has an append method, you could formData.append('list', 'string value');  If you need to cast tests as a string, you could use JSON.stringify(tests).

Comment: @MichaelFuller I'm using formData.append() and at least the post request is including now the file and the list, which answers the question, I'm having another issue to retrieve the list in the controller but that's a different question, if you want post your comment as an answer and I'll select it  as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes,it is possible.

As explained here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Just make sure that they have values (try and `console.log` it) and you also might need to `JSON.stringify` the data you want to send to make sure it is in the right format.